# How to make a Dynamic PageViewController in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Anyone know how to make a dynamic pageView controller in SwiftUI, iOS 14? Something that displays pages that are a function of their date so that one can scroll left or right to look at data from the past, present and future.

```swift
struct DatePg: View
{
    let date: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(date.description)
    }
}
```

There is a new API that allows one to make a PageViewController with the TabView and a viewModifier. But the only examples I've seen are static. Here's an example of a static PageView.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIPageView: View
{
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("Hello")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .tag(0)
            Text("World")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .tag(1)
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

Already have something working using UIHostingController but passing NSManageObjectContext through the UIKit objects is cuasing problems.

Here's where I'm at so far. Still not working.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main struct PagerApp: App
{
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup { DatePageView() }
    }
}

struct DatePageView: View
{
    @StateObject var dateData = DateData(present: Date())
    @State var index: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $index) {
            ForEach(dateData.dates, id: \.self) { date in
                Text(date.description)
                    .onAppear { dateData.current(date: date) }
                    .tag(dateData.tag(date: date))
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

class DateData: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var dates: [Date]
    
    init(present: Date) {
        let past = present.previousDay()
        let future = present.nextDay()
        self.dates = [past, present, future]
    }
    
    func current(date: Date) {
        //center around
        guard let i = dates.firstIndex(of: date) else { fatalError() }
        self.dates = [ dates[i].previousDay(), dates[i], dates[i].nextDay() ]
        print("make item at \(i) present")
    }
    
    func tag(date: Date) -> Int {
        guard let i = dates.firstIndex(of: date) else { fatalError() }
        return i
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? im trying to implement the same functionality

Answer (score 3):

You can create view dynamically using an array and `ForEach`.

Here is an example using an array of strings:

```swift
// See edited section
```

You could pass the items you want in the View initializer

**Edit:**
Here is an example for adding a new page each time I reach the last one:

```swift
struct SwiftUIPageView: View
{
    @State private var selection = "0"
    
    @State var items: [String] = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .tag(item)
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        .onChange(of: selection, perform: { value in
            if Int(value) == (self.items.count - 1) {
                self.items.append("\(self.items.count)")
            }
        })
        .id(items)
    }
}
```

The last `id(items)` is important because it forces the View to reload when the array changes.

Comment: that's cool, but that's still static. is there a way to make the datasource dynamic and use ForEach? the idea being that you swipe left and go a day in the past and swipe right and go a day in the future.

Comment: I managed to dynamically adding a View each time I reach the last one, but when it is added, there is no animation because the whole View is rendered, check the edit

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with creating SwiftUI wrapper around good old UIPageViewController

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    
    var index: Int
    
    init(index: Int, content: Content) {
        self.index = index
        
        super.init(rootView: content)
    }
    
    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This VC is intended for SwfitUI use init(index:, content:) instead")
    }

}

struct PageViewControllerSwiftUI<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int // track current page index
    
    let stopCondition: (Int) -> Bool
    let contentFactory: (Int) -> Content
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        // Regular UIKit staff of UIPageViewController
        
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
            options: nil
        )
        
        // Our context will perform role of dataSource nad delegate of created VC
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        if let startingViewController = context.coordinator
            .createPage(for: currentIndex) {
            pageViewController.setViewControllers(
                [startingViewController],
                direction: .forward,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
        
        return pageViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        // currentIndex changes handled here
        
        if let currentViewController = context.coordinator.createPage(for: currentIndex),
           let visibleViewController = uiViewController.viewControllers?.first as? PageContentViewController<Content>,
           visibleViewController.index != currentIndex {
            
            uiViewController.setViewControllers(
                [currentViewController],
                direction: currentIndex > visibleViewController.index ? .forward : .reverse,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        
        var view: PageViewControllerSwiftUI
        
        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewControllerSwiftUI) {
            self.view = pageViewController
        }
        
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

            let index = view.currentIndex - 1
            
            guard !view.stopCondition(index) else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return createPage(for: index)
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

            let index = view.currentIndex + 1
            
            guard !view.stopCondition(index) else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return createPage(for: index)
        }
        
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            
            if completed, let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? PageContentViewController<Content> {
                view.currentIndex = visibleViewController.index
            }
        }
        
        func createPage(for index: Int) -> PageContentViewController<Content>? {
            PageContentViewController(index: index, content: view.contentFactory(index))
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    struct PageViewControllerSwiftUIPreview: View {
        @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
        
        var body: some View {
            PageViewControllerSwiftUI(
                currentIndex: $currentIndex,
                stopCondition: { index in abs(index) > 10 } // here you can limit number of pages depending on index or just return false if you want infinite changes
            ) { index in
                // Create your date or whatever according to current index
                Text(
                    Calendar.current
                    .date(byAdding: .day, value: index, to: Date())!
                    .formatted(.dateTime)
                )
            }
        }

    }
    
    return PageViewControllerSwiftUIPreview()
}
```

The final result is completely dynamic PageViewController but embedded into SwiftUI and creating SwiftUI views.

Here the result:

[image]

Comment: What a professional implementation for the Page controller in SwiftUI! This is the best I have seen. Also I love the wrapper around PageContentViewController with the index inside. Super thanks, this is truly useful.